# Change foot height for different page styles

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, typearea, pagestyle

I am using the `scrlayer-scrpage` package to set page head and foot differently for the first page and subsequent pages: The first page has only a foot, but no head, and all other pages only have a head, but no foot. I am using the page style `plain.scrheadings` for the first page and `scrheadings` for the others.

Since the foot on the first page is larger than usual, I am setting the foot height with the option `footlines=2.1`. However, this leads to quite large empty space on the other pages. I would like to re-define this (or the `footheight` option for the `srcheadings` style (or generally, after the first page). Since I am not printing page numbers, it could ideally be 0.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Here’s a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[footlines=2.1]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{showframe}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\title{Footer Test}

\cohead{column title}
\rofoot[First footer\\with two lines]{}
\cofoot[]{}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain.scrheadings}

\maketitle

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is a missunderstanding in your question: footlines=2.1 does not enlarge the bottom margin. It only moves the footer in the bottom margin down. If you want to decrease the bottom height you have to use package `geometry` and class option `usegeometry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [esdd’s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491633/change-foot-height-for-different-page-styles?noredirect=1#comment1241532_491633) I figured out a solution:

I am now using the `geometry` package and a combination of

- `footlines` to set the height of the foot used for `footskip`,
- a manually set bottom margin,
- `footskip=0pt` to merge the foot into the text area, and
- `enlargethispage{-5\baselineskip}` to create space for the foot on the first page.

```
\documentclass[footlines=2.1, usegeometry=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{showframe}  % Only to show page layout
\usepackage[bottom=3.7cm,footskip=0pt]{geometry}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\title{Footer Test}

\cohead{column title}
\rofoot[First footer\\with two lines]{}
\cofoot[]{}

\begin{document}

% Switch page style for first page
\thispagestyle{plain.scrheadings}

\maketitle

% Add space for footer on first page
\enlargethispage{-5\baselineskip}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This produces the desired effect.

[image]